# Taking a photo and uploading to google cloud services on a phone

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, image-uploading, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a project where I need to upload an image to google cloud services..

The question is what are the steps that you take to upload an image to google cloud services in the web browser, I would prefer to upload it directly to google cloud services on the client side rather than uploading to my webserver and then uploading to google. Seems like that would take too many steps.

A little background is that this will take place in a mobile web browser..

Steps:
- A user will take a photo after clicking a button that launches their camera
- They will click save and the image will be uploaded directly to google cloud services, which will return a given id for that image to be stored in a table

I have read google cloud services documentation, yet primarily the information I found was related directly to android/ios for storage. I understand that you cannot upload an image using ajax, yet you can do it within an iframe. Is it possible to get the image binary data and convert it to base64 and then upload that string to google cloud services in order to store the data?

TLDR:
- What are the steps in order to upload an image to google cloud services?

Answer (score 0):

In google App engine it is possible to upload image by converting to base64 but you will need to convert it again into binary `blob` type from base64 to store it.

It is possible to upload a image directly to google app engine just by using a single html form having `<input file="" name="fileupload"/>` on client side.  Endpoint will be the servlet address on google appengine which handle this form request.

On the server side toy just need to get parameters of submitted form. Assign parameter named `fileupload` into blob type and then save using `entity` or in `resource`.

**update:** Submitting a from is possible through ajax without reloading but simple jquery/javascript don't support `form` submission which has `input` tag of file type therefore, a jquery [plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) used to do this :

Ex:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#submitForm').ajaxForm(function(result) {
                    // Do some DOM operation like hiding loader
                }).submit();
         });
```

Comment: So does this mean that I get the blob data on the client side? From what I understand when you use a file picker it returns a file path.

Comment: In which language? If from html it send file data to server which is blob.

Comment: Well I want this upload to happen without reloading the page. So I would assume this would need to be done using javascript. Ashwin